# Minimum partitions of Spark DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-science

Can someone help me understand how to work with changing the max partition byte configuration to enable a minimum of 2 partitions when reading each file in Spark SQL (so each dataframe 2 should have at least 4 partitions when reading from the given datafiles)?

Answer (score 0):

The 'maxPartitionBytes' option gives you the number of bytes stored in a partition. The default is **128 MB**. If you can manipulate the default capacity according to the file size you have to load, the minimum number of partitions will change accordingly.
For example if your loading a file of 90 MB then 1 partition will be created. If you use the below function to change the configuration,

SparkConf().set("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes", "")

and change the number of bytes to 52428800 (50 MB),
ie SparkConf().set("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes", 52428800)
then the maximum capacity for the partition size will decrease, and 2 partitions will be created.

In the brackets you have to place the amount of storage in '**bytes**'.